# Log in on 3rd party website using Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I need to solve the following problem: I created two applications using Laravel.

- **Application A** can be reached via `https://test.example.org` and provides a passport-instance and all user-data (Model: `User`).
- **Application B** can be reached via `https://test.org` and uses the API **Application A** provides using an "api-user" that exists in **Application A** to fetch "public" data

Now I would like to provide a login method for users of **Application B**. All users that are using **Application B** are existing in **Application A**. So a user logging in on **Application B** is using the credentials that are saved in **Application A**. All changes that are made to the user in **Application A** should be visible on **Application B**.

Now I wonder how I could do that. Any idea how to solve this? I can imagine using API-calls with

```
        $client = $this->client;
        try {
            return $client->request('POST',
                'https://'.config('server').'/oauth/token', [
                    'headers'     => [
                        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
                        'Content-Type'  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    ],
                    'form_params' => [
                        'client_id'     => ...,
                        'client_secret' => ...,
                        'grant_type'    => 'password',
                        'username'      => $users-username,
                        'password'      => $users-password,
                    ],
                ]);
        } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
            return $e->getResponse();
        }
    }
```

but I don't get, whether I need to create a `client_id` and `client_secret` for each user on **Application A**. If this is the case, I'd need to store these information somewhere so I'd end up creating a `User` model on **Application B** itself.

### My questions are:

- How can I log in users that are existing on **Application A** to **Application B** the most elegant way?
- Is it an option to use Laravel/Socialite from the client side (**Application B**)?

Comment: You would only create one `client_id` and `client_secret` for Application B

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most elegant way would be to use Laravel Socialite in your **Application B** to act as an OAuth client for **Application A** which acts as an OAuth server (using Laravel Passport).

1. On **Application A**, you need to [create a client](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#managing-clients) on Passport for your **Application B**:

```sh
php artisan passport:client --password
```

First, you will be asked `Which user ID should the client be assigned to?`. Press enter as you don't want to restrict the client to a specific user.

Then, you will be asked to provide a name for your client, your should enter something like `Application B`.

At last, you will be asked for the redirect URL of you client. You should enter `https://test.org/oauth/callback`, which is the URL that Socialite will use to redirect the users back after they are authenticated.

If you need to test this on your machine, enter your local domain, e.g. `https://application-b.test/oauth/callback`.

Once the client is created, keep the Client ID and Client secret as you will need them later.

You will also need an API endpoint to provide the details for the authenticated user, .e.g. `https://test.example.org/user`.

2. On **Application B**, after [installing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite#installation) Laravel Socialite, you need to set the credentials for the **Application A** in your `services.php` configuration file. For example:

```php
'passport' => [
    'client_id' => env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'oauth/callback',
],
```

In your `.env` file, set the client ID and secret for the Passport client you created in **Application A**:

```
PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID=...
PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET=...
```

3. Now you need to extend Socialite with a custom provider for `Application A`.

Create a `PassportProvider` class in the `app/Socialite` directory (or anywhere inside `app` if you prefer).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Socialite;

use Laravel\Socialite\Two\AbstractProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\ProviderInterface;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class PassportProvider extends AbstractProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase('https://test.example.org/oauth/authorize', $state);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return 'https://test.example.org/oauth/token';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
            'https://test.example.org/user',
            $this->getRequestOptions($token)
        );

        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id' => $user['id'],
            'name' => Arr::get($user, 'name'),
            'email' => Arr::get($user, 'email'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the default options for an HTTP request.
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getRequestOptions($token)
    {
        return [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'token '.$token,
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Next, in your `ApplicationServiceProvider` (or in a separate service provider), add the following:

```php
use App\Socialite\PassportProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

public function boot()
{
    Socialite::extend('passport', function (function ($app) {
        $config = $app['config']['services.passport'];

        return new PassportProvider(
            $app['request'],
            $config['client_id'],
            $config['client_secret'],
            URL::to($config['redirect'])
        );
    });
}
```

Now you are ready to use your custom Socialite provider in your [login controller](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite#routing) on your client application:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('passport')->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('passport')->user();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the login routes in your `routes/web.php` file:

```php
Route::get('oauth/redirect', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('oauth/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Answer (score 0):

A. You would only create one client_id and client_secret for Application B
B. Use Passport as you wrote above
C. You can, but you need to set it up manually which I'm not sure is a good idea, a better one would be to redirect it to Application A UI (In case of web) or directly contact Application A (in case of mobile) and let it handle it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

there is two solutions

**1.** If you just need **Application A** database details than create multiple database connection in your **Application B**

https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

**2.** If you want to access **Application A** endpoint than keep same files storage/oauth-public.key, storage/oauth-private.key for your both Application so **Application A** can easily Authenticate **Application B** authorisation token.